# Can't install USB Google driver on Win10

Tags: android

I can't debug and run my apps in device, because when I click "run" in An
 droidStudio my device go to offline.

I found solution in stack, exacly: install usb Google driver.
But when I try to install driver from my local folders, I got massange

> "The windows system is set up with the best driver installed"

So how do I install another driver, since Windows knows better and installs one that does not work?

Comment: Are you sure you need to?  I haven't needed to use that driver in several years

Comment: when i plug my device to pc, widows give me information "windows does not recognize device "